# Publishing android app on PlayStore Takes more then 10 days

Tags: android, google-developers-console

this is my first app that i publish and it's taking more the 10 days to review
i know due to the COVID-19 things may take time but i think 10 days are too long even with that considered
and am still in internal test stage
how long does this process take usually ?

Comment: It shouldn't take that long. I do beta releases often. It usually happens in 1-2 days, even during Covid. Sometimes it can take upto 3-5 days, but never more than that. I assume similar time periods should be applicable for internal releases.

Comment: New apps will take a longer time than updates to existing ones. I would wait a few more days and contact developer support after that.

Comment: Yesterday I have updated an app, it takes only 2 hours to live, so, I guess in your case, there is another problem for a new app, you may contact for developer support.

Comment: I got problem too. Before 2021, an update would have take few hours to be Live. Now it takes several days! I did contact the support, but they don't provide any valuable informations.

Comment: If you are releasing your app for the first time, It will take some time, further updates will take less time, you can also release beta versions than promote them to production

Answer (score 2):

Here are my conclusions based on what happened to me in the same situation:

**Apps in Internal test Stage will not be reviewed**. So they will just stay as "waiting for review" or something like that. Despite of that, your registered testers still can open the link, accept to be a tester and download the app. Unfortunately, I have no reference to this other than my own experience.

I waited for almost 2 weeks before trying it for myself (using my personal account as a test user) and checking that the app was working just fine (only for testers, of course). My first release was in August/2021 (we're in October/2021 by now) and it still not verified.

Comment: @MelikBOZKURT Jan/2023: This app specifically is still not reviewed. But please note: it is in INTERNAL TEST PHASE. I think it will only ever get reviewd If I promote it manually to a release or Open Test version. Probably Internal Test Phase Apps don't get reviewed and that's it, but I couldn't find anything commenting about this in their documentation.

Comment: I think the only thing you can do is to follow the pipeline: Make the Internal Test an Open Test, then Launch. I think when it comes to the launch phase the "Not Reviewed" will have some meaning. For now, it looks just like an alias or default phrase for everything that has not been reviewed, wheter because it is awaiting for an actual review (like a published app) or never will be reviewed (like an Internal Test App)

Answer (score 0):

even for a simple apps with just auth and registration, they may take 15 days they are like keep it slow ,reviewer replied me send me user credential I replied immediately he came after 2 days told me auth not working I fixed it now after two days he may come back. i hope someone will take over this process and world get better app store

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).